# What is the .= (dot equals) operator in PHP?

Tags: php

What does the following line mean, particularly the operator `.=`?

```
$query .= "UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;";
```

in [the code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php)

```
<?php

$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=publisher");

// these statements will be executed as one transaction

$query = "UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1;";
$query .= "UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;";

pg_query($conn, $query);

?>
```

It seems to make some sort of array such that the last command processes first the first query and then the second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the concatenate assignment operator.  It will concatenate or add to the end of the string. So:

```
$a = "Hi!";

$a .= " I";
$a .= " love";
$a .= " StackOverflow";
$a .= " a";
$a .= " lot";

echo $a; // echos "Hi! I love StackOverflow a lot"
```

In your case

```
$query = "UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1;";
$query .= "UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;";
echo $query; 
/* echos "UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1; UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2; */
```

Answer (score 3):

It means `$query = $query . "UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;";`

So it appends the String to the Query Variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about the operator `.=`. It is a **shorthand to a *string concatenation* followed by an *assignment***.

#### On *assigment by operation* operators

There is a family of operators we can call **assignment by xyz**, where **xyz** here represents a binary operation on operands of the same type, such as addition, subtraction, concatenation.

So, let's say we have an operator ⊕: `int`*`int` → `int`, meaning that it takes a pair of `int`s and produces another one:

⊕(a, b) = a ⊕ b

Let's say we want to calculate `a`⊕`b` and store the results on the variable `a`. We can do so by:

a = a ⊕ b

But we do this so often when coding that an operator was created to represent the line above. You should take it as a single operation that does both the ⊕ operation and the assignment ( `=` ) with a single call:

a ⊕= b ⇔ a = a ⊕ b.

#### Some examples

So, in your case, you have a `.=` operator. Now that you know about *assignment by operation* operators, you can guess that:

```
$query = "Hello, "
$query .= "World!";
```

is the same as:

```
$query = "Hello, "
$query = $query . "World!";
```

See?

Now, another frequent use of this kind operators are the `+=` and `-=` versions.

However, abuse of this kinds of operators may lead to less readable code (especially when dealing with "low level" operators acting on bits, for example).

Answer (score 1):

`.=` simply means "append". This

```
$query = "UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1;";
$query .= "UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;";
```

…results in

```
$query == "UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1;UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Concatenates** the string... so `$query` becomes:

```
"UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1;UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;"
```

Answer (score 0):

it separates the updates with ; and executes both of them